# Creating new array by merging array of objects based on some conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of objects.

```
const array1=[
{type:'A',name:'word1'},
{type:'B',name:'word2'},
{type:'C',name:'word3'},
{type:'D',name:'word4'},
{type:'E',name:'word5'},
{type:'F',name:'word6'},
]

const array2=[
{id:1,text:'text1',type:A},
{id:2,text:'text2',type:B},
{id:3,text:'text3',type:C},
{id:4,text:'text4',type:D},
{id:5,text:'text5',type:D},
{id:6,text:'text6',type:E},
{id:7,text:'text7',type:E},
{id:8,text:'text8',type:B},
]
```

There are some types which are in array1 but not in array 2. I want to display the newArray in the following way:-

```
const newArray=[
{id:1,text:'text1',type:A,name:'word1'},
{id:2,text:'text2',type:B,name:'word2'},
{id:3,text:'text3',type:C,name:'word3'},
{id:4,text:'text4',type:D,name:'word4'},
{id:5,text:'text5',type:D,name:'word4'},
{id:6,text:'text6',type:E,name:'word5'},
{id:7,text:'text7',type:E,name:'word5'},
{id:8,text:'text8',type:B,name:'word2'},
]
```

I have tried doing it:-

```
var newArray=[],
newArray=array1.map(x => Object.assign(x, array2.filter(y => y.type == x.type)));
```

But i am not getting output in the required form.

Comment: First of all, since the new array is based on array2, you need to use `array2.map()`.

Comment: Is `type` in array2 a string?

Comment: Looks like you want this: `const newArray = array2.map(x => Object.assign(x, {name: array1.find(y => y.type == x.type).name}));`

Comment: Can you please edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `type` in array2 should be `string`.
Else it should reference to a variable.

And as i you use `map` and `find` methods of array.
You can improve your solution like this:

```js
const newArr = array2.map(x => ({...x, name: array1.find(y => y.type === x.type).name }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `array1` to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is keyed by the type and stores the `name` for its values. You can then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `array2` to add a `name` property to each object based on the associated value from the `Map`

```js
const array1 = [ {type:'A',name:'word1'}, {type:'B',name:'word2'}, {type:'C',name:'word3'}, {type:'D',name:'word4'}, {type:'E',name:'word5'}, {type:'F',name:'word6'},];
const array2 = [ {id:1,text:'text1',type:'A'}, {id:2,text:'text2',type:'B'}, {id:3,text:'text3',type:'C'}, {id:4,text:'text4',type:'D'}, {id:5,text:'text5',type:'D'}, {id:6,text:'text6',type:'E'}, {id:7,text:'text7',type:'E'}, {id:8,text:'text8',type:'B'}, ];

const typeMap = new Map(array1.map(({type, name}) => [type, name]));
const newArr = array2.map(o => ({...o, name: typeMap.get(o.type)}));
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const array1=[
{type:'A',name:'word1'},
{type:'B',name:'word2'},
{type:'C',name:'word3'},
{type:'D',name:'word4'},
{type:'E',name:'word5'},
{type:'F',name:'word6'},
]

const array2=[
{id:1,text:'text1',type:'A'},
{id:2,text:'text2',type:'B'},
{id:3,text:'text3',type:'C'},
{id:4,text:'text4',type:'D'},
{id:5,text:'text5',type:'D'},
{id:6,text:'text6',type:'E'},
{id:7,text:'text7',type:'E'},
{id:8,text:'text8',type:'B'},
]

const a = array2.map(arr => {
    const {name} = array1.filter(iArr => iArr.type === arr.type)[0];
    return {...arr, name} 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to create an object Map out of Array1 so that you can search in constant time. Post that you can map over array to and return the updated objected using spread syntax

```js
const array1=[
{type:'A',name:'word1'},
{type:'B',name:'word2'},
{type:'C',name:'word3'},
{type:'D',name:'word4'},
{type:'E',name:'word5'},
{type:'F',name:'word6'},
]

const array2=[
{id:1,text:'text1',type:'A'},
{id:2,text:'text2',type:'B'},
{id:3,text:'text3',type:'C'},
{id:4,text:'text4',type:'D'},
{id:5,text:'text5',type:'D'},
{id:6,text:'text6',type:'E'},
{id:7,text:'text7',type:'E'},
{id:8,text:'text8',type:'B'},
]


const map = Object.assign({}, ...array1.map(item => ({[item.type]: item.name})))

const res = array2.map(obj => ({
   ...obj,
   name: map[obj.type]
}))

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to map over the `array2` to return a new array of objects based on the `type` key comparison between the two arrays, as so:

```js
const array1=[
{type:'A',name:'word1'},
{type:'B',name:'word2'},
{type:'C',name:'word3'},
{type:'D',name:'word4'},
{type:'E',name:'word5'},
{type:'F',name:'word6'},
]

const array2=[
{id:1,text:'text1',type:'A'},
{id:2,text:'text2',type:'B'},
{id:3,text:'text3',type:'C'},
{id:4,text:'text4',type:'D'},
{id:5,text:'text5',type:'D'},
{id:6,text:'text6',type:'E'},
{id:7,text:'text7',type:'E'},
{id:8,text:'text8',type:'B'},
]

const newArray = array2.map(x => Object.assign(x, {name: array1.find(y => y.type == x.type).name}));

console.log(newArray)//test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try with `forEach` loop.

```js
var array1=[
{type:'A',name:'word1'},
{type:'B',name:'word2'},
{type:'C',name:'word3'},
{type:'D',name:'word4'},
{type:'E',name:'word5'},
{type:'F',name:'word6'},
]

var array2=[
{id:1,text:'text1',type:'A'},
{id:2,text:'text2',type:'B'},
{id:3,text:'text3',type:'C'},
{id:4,text:'text4',type:'D'},
{id:5,text:'text5',type:'D'},
{id:6,text:'text6',type:'E'},
{id:7,text:'text7',type:'E'},
{id:8,text:'text8',type:'B'},
]

array2.forEach((v)=>{
    type=array1.find(({type})=>type==v.type);
    v = Object.assign(v, type);
});

console.log(array2);
```